# Webmethod call from jQuery AJAX gives 404 Error

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, iis-7.5, webmethod

**UPDATE**

I have used:  under `<system.WebServer>` in `web.config`, which solved the problem. I cannot find a good explanation to the question "why so" anywhere. So for the sake of future comers to this question, please share your knowledge with us..

---

I am posting only one example of this, but it is the same issue with all my WebMethod calls throughout my site.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Settings.aspx/myFunction",
    data: "{'pagename': '" + elid + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {
       ' do something
    }
});
```

when this (or other) WebMethods are called, I am getting a "HTTP 404.0 The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." error.

I guess it is looking for "`myFunction`" as a seperate web page instead of a method function..

myFunction is declared as below in Settings.aspx.vb

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function myFunction(pagename As String) As String
    ' code not shown for clarity
End Function
```

`System.Web.Services` namespace is also imported.

Everything works as expected on my development machine but it does not work on the production server. I suspect it is something to to with the configuration settings but this is a clone project of another couple of other projects which works just fine on the same machine with the same code..

I have gone through the web.config and made sure everything else are the same with the other cloned web sites.

I am on a dedicated windows 2008 server with IIS 7.5 installed and Plesk.

Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: Have a look at the developers tools (IE, Chrome) or firebug and taje a look at where you are posting ajax request

Comment: Hi @Leo, posting to the correct place.. As I said, code works fine on development machine.. There must be something with the configuration...

Comment: @Emin, I have same error and I have no solution. When you get solution than please let me know.